# Issue excluding records from output using awk

Tags: awk

I have been having an issue whereby the number of records being excluded from my output is more than expected. Below is a list of ID's which I am trying to exclude from an output, and the code which I am using

Sample Data;

```
1|ABC|DEF
2|ABC|DEF
3|ABC|DEF
21|ABC|DEF
```

List of ID's to exclude

```
1
2
```

I have converted the list into a pipe delimited string, and fed it in using the below awk command, however the output is excluding more records than is expected. I suspect this is because it is not searching for an exact match.

```
UNAPPROVED_IDS='1|2'
awk -F'|' -v UNAPPROVED_IDS="$UNAPPROVED_IDS" '$1 !~ "UNAPPROVED_IDS"' input.csv >> output.txt
```

Is there a way to ensure that only ID's 1&2 from the list are excluded from the output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Drop the quotes around `UNAPPROVED_IDS` i.e. just `$1 !~ UNAPPROVED_IDS`

Comment: but you need to make it `UNAPPROVED_IDS='^(1|2)$'` to make it even more strict

Comment: Should this be added as part of the awk command, or resolved before? Cant seem to get it to work UNAPPROVED_IDS='^(1|2)$'

Comment: Like before. `UNAPPROVED_IDS='^(1|2)$'; awk -F'|' -v UNAPPROVED_IDS="$UNAPPROVED_IDS" '$1 !~ UNAPPROVED_IDS' input.csv >> output.txt`